# How to return a boolean from a function in java? getting an error

Tags: java

```
public class Test {
    public boolean checkx(boolean x) {
        boolean status;
        if (x) {
            status = true;
        }
        return status;
    }
}
```

> Error: The local variable status may not have been initialized

I don't know what I was doing wrong, code looks alright to me.

Comment: If you do not enter the `if` block then what is the value of `boolean status;` ?

Comment: If you are going to set `status` to false when `x` is false, then why not just return `x` ?

Comment: @ScaryWombat ohh got it. thanks

Comment: This is one of the Java rules. you can read about Java language specifications here https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-16.html. to solve the issue initiate the boolean status to 'false'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the [Java Language Speciication](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se15/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.5), it is written that:

> A local variable (§14.4, §14.14) must be explicitly given a value
> before it is used, by either initialization (§14.4) or assignment
> (§15.26), in a way that can be verified using the rules for definite
> assignment (§16 (Definite Assignment)).

So, you must have to initialize or assign a value to the local variable before using it.

In your particular example:

```
public boolean checkx(boolean x) {
    boolean status = false;
    if (x) {
        status = true;
    }
    return status;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're doing it way to complicated. You can check the status of a boolean by writing:

```
if(x == true)
        // Do Something
```

or even simpler:

```
if(x)
        // Do Something
```

Or you can write a function to get x from another class. In case the x is private:

```
public boolean getX() {
    return x;
}
```